# Cas authentication and database authorizing

Tags: database, spring-security, cas

I've googled around to get started from stracht in this new thing to me.Is it possible to authenticate user with cas and then give roles from own database? I'm using Spring 3 and Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own AuthenticationProvider and load the user data from any source you wish. For example you may wrap the CasAuthenticationProvider and add whatever you need.

have a look at the docs: [CAS Authentication documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html)
there is also a [CAS sample in the repository](https://s3browse.springsource.com/browse/maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework/security/spring-security-samples-cas/).

Answer (score 0):

At the cas server end you need to provide your own authentication handler.

As far as the roles. at the application end you can write you own class which implements UserDetailsService and configure it in the casAuthenticationProvider

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html

In case you need to load all the roles at the cas end have a look at the ldap implementation

http://bowerstudios.com/node/645

You may have to do a similar thru database